# sudo apt update always givies: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)

Tags: apt, updates

I am new user of Ubuntu (21.10) and I am having some problems with updating my packages with "sudo apt-get update". I know there are already a lot of threads fixing this problem, but I am a complete beginner and don't know how to use these fixes for my specific problem.
Thank you for your patience!

[the terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aX7us.png)

Comment: were you able to solve the problem with the help of the linked question?

Comment: @Zanna yeah thanks, It took me a while but I finally got it to work! Thx!